# Can a 3 foot gnome disguise as an orc?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, disguise

In my campaign, I have an enemy that is a short little 3 foot gnome rogue.

The gnome is level 20 and their disguise skill is 23. With the Master of Disguise skill, that would increase to 33.

Would it be possible for this little gnome to disguise themselves as something large, such as an orc? Or will size actually matter in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

The rules for [Disguise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/disguise) explicitly call out a penalty for disguising yourself as a different size category: -10.  Since you're disguising yourself as a different race that is one size category larger than you, you make a normal Disguise check at -12.

Comment: Ahh ha, I didn't see that little line on that page. Thank you so much.